# Render HTML from array items

Tags: html, arrays, reactjs

I am attempting to render a list of HTML elements (links) stored in an array.

I am initially constructing the array as such:

```
const availableSizes = product.simples.filter((value) => {
        return value.stockStatus === STATUS_AVAILABLE;
}).map((value, index) => {
        return `${value.filterValue} `;
});
```

An example of the array contents is :

```
["35 ", "36 ", "36.5 ", "37.5 ", "38 ", "39 ", "39.5 ", "40 ", "41 ", "41.5 ", "42 ", "42.5 ", "43 ", "44 ", "44.5 ", "45 ", "46 ", "46.5 ", "48 ", "49 "]
```

I attempted to modify how each string is built as such:

```
const availableSizes = product.simples.filter((value) => {
        return value.stockStatus === STATUS_AVAILABLE;
}).map((value, index) => {
        return `<a href="#">${value.filterValue}</a>`;
});
```

but the HTML was escaped and printed directly in the output without it being parsed as HTML but as a common string.

Please note that not only I need to render the links but I also need to have onClick handlers that do specific actions (save a cookie for example), so the links need to be handled by React as well.

Comment: Are you using jsx? If yes why not `return <a key={index}>{value.filterValue}</a>` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doing it how Yury says will fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have JSX available you could do the following instead:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const availableSizes = product.simples
      .filter((value) => value.stockStatus === STATUS_AVAILABLE)
      .map((value, index) => <a key={index} href="#">${value.filterValue}</a>);

    return (
      <div>
        {availableSizes}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pay attention to the `key={index}` that I added.  React needs this to optimise the rendering process.  If you have a unique id for each product you could use that instead for a better optimisation.  It's used in React's diffing algorithm.  For example:  `<a key={value.id} href="#">${value.filterValue}</a>`

Comment: you're not returning something from map and there's a JS error thrown :/

Comment: The return is implicit when you have a single expression within an anonymous function.

Comment: indeed, in my code I used the {  } notation so I guess it expected a return.

Answer (score 3):

In `.map` you return `String` however you should return [`JSX`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

```
const availableSizes = product.simples.filter((value) => {
  return value.stockStatus === STATUS_AVAILABLE;
}).map((value, index) => {
  return <a key={ index } href="#">{ value.filterValue }</a>;
});
```